# Parse a json/dictionary with same key values

Tags: python, json

I currently have a list variable that looks like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{"Away_Team":"KC", "Home_Team":"NYY"},
                 {"Away_Team":"TB", "Home_Team":"MIA"},
                 {"Away_Team":"TOR", "Home_Team":"BOS"},
]
```

As you can see, there are multiple keys with the same names, pertaining to the game matchups.

When I try to use:

```
print(json.dumps(list_of_dicts[0], indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

...it only prints out the first matchup due to the same keys:

```
{
    "Away_Team": "KC",
    "Home_Team": "NYY"
}
```

How can I convert this `list_of_dicts` variable into something like the following output so I can use it like a valid dictionary or json object?

```
{
    "Away_Team_1":"KC", "Home_Team_1":"NYY",
    "Away_Team_2":"TB", "Home_Team_2":"MIA",
    "Away_Team_3":"TOR", "Home_Team_3":"BOS",
}
```

This output doesn't need to be exactly that if a better solution is available, this is just to give you an idea of how I'd like to be able to parse the data.

The `list_of_dicts` variable can be of varying sizes, I've shown 3 here, but it could contain 1 or 10 matchups, it varies, so the solution needs to be dynamic to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add suffixes to the keys with `enumerate`:

```py
list_of_dicts2 = [{f"{k}_{i}":v for k,v in d.items()} for i,d in enumerate(list_of_dicts, start=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use pandas:

```
pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts).to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

gives

```
Away_Team,Home_Team
KC,NYY
TB,MIA
TOR,BOS
```

Now the index is implied by the row, and if you load it back in you'll have those indices. Pandas also supports `to_json` if you are hard set on using `json` though. You can even recover your original list from a dataframe using `.to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 1):

Data structure is important.  You really don't need a dictionary for this.  Simply reducing to a list of tuples the first slot always the away team, and the second the home team.

```
list_of_dicts = [{"Away_Team":"KC", "Home_Team":"NYY"},
                 {"Away_Team":"TB", "Home_Team":"MIA"},
                 {"Away_Team":"TOR", "Home_Team":"BOS"},
]

l = [tuple(l.values()) for l in list_of_dicts]
```

output:

```
[('KC', 'NYY'), ('TB', 'MIA'), ('TOR', 'BOS')]
```

The problem with your proposed solution is iterating through dicts where you don't know the key name is cumbersome, this solution makes the data structure easy to decipher, transform, or manipulate.